# NodeJS spellchecker get the corrected sentence

Tags: node.js

I am using the NodeJS spellchecker module here https://www.npmjs.com/package/spellchecker and passing a sentence to be checked using

```
SpellChecker.checkSpelling('Show me the car parsk in Mlebourne CBD') // Misspellings intentional
```

I'm getting the array values back with the start/end index of an incorrect word. The problem I'm facing (and can't find documented anywhere) is how do I get the full corrected sentence back, not just the indexes?

Thanks

Comment: With the indexes extract the word and call SpellChecker.getCorrectionsForMisspelling(word)

Comment: Thanks @rodrigoap was hoping there was a single pass option but understand there could be more than 1 correction option.